# Update the record according to the ID of inserted record in LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I want to insert a record and then update the record according to scope_identity of inserted record.
I'm doing this but when I want to update my record encounter an error.

```
WorkshopDataContext Dac = new WorkshopDataContext();
Dac.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=dpsxxx-xxx;Initial Catalog=kar;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx";
Tbl_workshop Workshop = new Tbl_workshop();
Workshop.StateCode = Bodu.BduStateCode;
Workshop.CityCode = Bodu.BduCityCode;
Workshop.Co_workshop=12222;
Dac.Tbl_workshop.InsertOnSubmit(Workshop);
Dac.SubmitChanges();
Int64 Scope = Workshop.id;
var query = from record in Dac.Tbl_workshop where record.id == Scope select record;
        query.First().co_Workshop = Scope;
Dac.SubmitChanges();
```

and this is the error:

```
Value of member 'co_Workshop' of an object of type 'Tbl_Workshop' changed.
A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed.
Consider adding a new object with new identity and deleting the existing one instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

As it said on the error, you can't change co_Workshop because its identity (auto increment value). To freely edit it, you need to edit the database and remove this setting.

What probably is happening is that both id and co_Workshop are set as identity. Just disable the identity checkbox from co_Workshop.

Comment: No `Co_Workshop` is not identity, it's just primary key

Comment: Check the Linq DBML then, maybe it's not in sync

Comment: I checked it, it's ok. Am I doing right for updating? I am inserting 12222 value in `co_kargah` and after the record is inserted I want to update it with the `id` of inserted record in the same table

Comment: try deleting this table and reinserting it in the DBML. double check if the column really isnt idendity

Comment: The second submit changes and just for this field. I tested it for the other filed and there is no error. However `Co_Workshop` is not identity and just is primary key. `StateCode` and `Co_workshop` are primary key

Comment: It's something in your DB definition. Just double check it and you will find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have properly configured your Linq-to-SQL model to reflect the `IDENTITY` column in your table, you should have the new value available right after `.SubmitChanges()`:

```
Tbl_workshop Workshop = new Tbl_workshop();
Workshop.StateCode = Bodu.BduStateCode;
Workshop.CityCode = Bodu.BduCityCode;
Workshop.Co_workshop=12222;

Dac.Tbl_workshop.InsertOnSubmit(Workshop);
Dac.SubmitChanges();

Int64 workshopID = Workshop.Id;  // you should get new ID value here - automatically!!
```

You don't need to do anything like reading out that new value from SQL Server or anything - Linq-to-SQL should automagically update your `Workshop` object with the proper value.

[image]

**Update:** to update your `co_workshop` value to the value given by the `IDENTITY ID`, do this (just set the value of `co_workshop` and save again - that's really all there is):

```
Dac.Tbl_workshop.InsertOnSubmit(Workshop);
Dac.SubmitChanges();

Int64 workshopID = Workshop.Id;  // you should get new ID value here - automatically!!

Workshop.Co_workshop = workshopID;
Dac.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: After getting the id of inserted record I want to update `Co_Workshop` with the `id` field. what should I do? 'Co_workshop' is not Identity it' just primary key

Comment: @Raymond Morphy: have you changed your database schema recently, and possibly not updated your Linq-to-SQL model after that??

Comment: @marc-s I think my problem is because of primary key. I have a compound primary key. `StateCode` and `Co_Workshop` are primary key together. when I want to update a primary key field I encounter this error. I tested it just for one table with a compound field an wanted to update one of it's primary key fields and encounter this error again. How can I update a primary key field? I don't have this problem when using transact SQL directly.